# Json to CLOB in java

Tags: java, json, oracle, clob

I have created a spring boot application for fetching json messages from Kafka and I need to save the messages using Oracle function. For calling the function I need to convert json to CLOB. Can we do the conversion of Json to CLOB in java?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is stored as CLOB.. What is the issue.